# in NetworkX cannot save a graph as jpg or png file

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, save, networkx

I have a graph in NetworkX containing some info. After the graph is shown, I want to save it as `jpg` or `png` file. I used the `matplotlib` function `savefig` but when the image is saved, it does not contain anything. It is just a white image.

Here is a sample code I wrote:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_title('Graph - Shapes', fontsize=10)

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node('shape1', level=1)
G.add_node('shape2', level=2)
G.add_node('shape3', level=2)
G.add_node('shape4', level=3)
G.add_edge('shape1', 'shape2')
G.add_edge('shape1', 'shape3')
G.add_edge('shape3', 'shape4')
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, node_size=1500, node_color='yellow', font_size=8, font_weight='bold')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.savefig("Graph.png", format="PNG")
```

Why is the image saved without anything inside (just white) ?

This is the image saved (just blank):
[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's related to `plt.show` method.

Help of `show` method:

```
def show(*args, **kw):
    """
    Display a figure.

    When running in ipython with its pylab mode, display all
    figures and return to the ipython prompt.

    In non-interactive mode, display all figures and block until
    the figures have been closed; in interactive mode it has no
    effect unless figures were created prior to a change from
    non-interactive to interactive mode (not recommended).  In
    that case it displays the figures but does not block.

    A single experimental keyword argument, *block*, may be
    set to True or False to override the blocking behavior
    described above.
    """
```

When you call `plt.show()` in your script,  it seems something like file object is still open, and `plt.savefig` method for writing can not read from that stream completely. but there is a `block` option for `plt.show` that can change this behavior, so you can use it:

```
plt.show(block=False)
plt.savefig("Graph.png", format="PNG")
```

Or just comment it:

```
# plt.show()
plt.savefig("Graph.png", format="PNG")
```

Or just save befor show it:

```
plt.savefig("Graph.png", format="PNG")
plt.show()
```

Demo: 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDRJ2.png)

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same problem. Looking at other comments and with the help of this link https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/06-Plotting-with-Matplotlib/06.04-Saving-Plots/ it worked for me! Two things that i had to change in my simple program was to add:
%matplotlib inline after importing matplotlib and save the figure before plt.show(). See my basic example:

```
    #importing the package
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline

    #initializing an empty graph
    G = nx.Graph()
    #adding one node
    G.add_node(1)
    #adding a second node
    G.add_node(2)
    #adding an edge between the two nodes (undirected)
    G.add_edge(1,2)

    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
    plt.savefig('plotgraph.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()
```

#dpi= specifies how many dots per inch (image resolution) are in the saved image, #bbox_inches='tight' is optional
#use plt.show() after saving. Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not work! it yields the same result as described in the question