# Using plt.savefig over a for loop of iterated plots returns blank image

Tags: python, matplotlib

Ok, so I apologize if this has been asked before, but I am running into some issues with trying to execute plt.savefig on some plots I want to save to a certain directory on my computer.

I currently have 481 plots that I generated through the following code:

```
ID=np.array(table['ID'])
```

My ID array comes from an isolated column from an astropy table which I made into an array to match the format of my other variables.

```
path=str('/Volumes/Desktop/Folder')
filename=str('/Filename_ID_')
outfilename=path+filename
outfilename
yra = [0, 3]


def PLOTS(M,P,Match,Mean,P25,P50,P75):
    ax=plt.subplot();
    return (plt.figure(),
            ax.plot(M,P,'b',lw=2),
            ax.plot((Match*np.ones(2)), yra, 'red',lw=3, label='match'),
            ax.plot((P25*np.ones(2)), yra, 'b--', label='P25'),
            ax.plot(P50*np.ones(2), yra, 'c--', label='P50',linewidth=4),
            ax.plot(P75*np.ones(2), yra, 'r--', label='P75'),
            ax.plot(Mean*np.ones(2), yra, 'darkgoldenrod',label='mean'),
            ax.set_xlabel('M',fontsize=14),
            ax.set_ylabel('P',fontsize=14),
            ax.legend(fontsize=10,loc='upper right'),
            plt.savefig(outfilename+str(ID)+'.pdf')));

for i in range(len(M)):
    print(PLOTS(M, P[i],Matches[i],Mean[i],P25[i],P50[i],P75[i]))
    plt.savefig(outfilename+str(ID[i])+'.pdf')
```

This outputs my plots but when I go check my Folder in my desktop the image is blank. 
I know that if you execute plt.show() before your plt.savefig() then that is the reason why you get a blank image, but I am not executing plt.show() at all. 
I have tried to add the plt.show() command after the plt.savefig commands on both my function and my for loop but I still come up with a blank image.

I have also checked out other posts similar to mine such as [How do I save a new graph as png with every iteration of a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38904461/how-do-i-save-a-new-graph-as-png-with-every-iteration-of-a-loop) but this still did not help with my issue.

I really appreciate any help you guys may provide and again apologize if this question has been asked.

Comment: why do you call plt.savefig twice? does it work if you change the format, e.g. to .png?

Comment: I called plt.savefig in the function and in the for loop hoping it would actually generate an image. I have tried using just plt.savefig in the for loop and it still doesn't work. I have also tried using '.png' format but it still outputs a blank image.

Comment: Have you tried not using print()  in the loop and just call the func PLOTS?
1. Have you tried printing out our ID array?  Seems to be a typo here ID=np.array(table[['ID'])
2. What are you really trying to return using the function def? Return only the plot. Put everything else inside the function.

Comment: I would define a figure and call `fig.savefig(...)`.

Comment: Can you try to NOT put all that plotting code in a tuple that is returned by the function `PLOTS`. Apart from being horrible code style, I am not sure whether this will work as intended.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud try to add  `plt.close()` the line after `plt.savefig(outfilename+str(ID[i])+'.pdf')`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).