# How to create an .exe for Networkx + Matplotlib in python that generates .png file

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

As the title, it fails every time I use Pyinstaller or py2exe to compile into .exe file.

I've tried this simple code taken from as the example
([in NetworkX cannot save a graph as jpg or png file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635538/in-networkx-cannot-save-a-graph-as-jpg-or-png-file))

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_title('Graph - Shapes', fontsize=10)

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node('shape1', level=1)
G.add_node('shape2', level=2)
G.add_node('shape3', level=2)
G.add_node('shape4', level=3)
G.add_edge('shape1', 'shape2')
G.add_edge('shape1', 'shape3')
G.add_edge('shape3', 'shape4')
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, node_size=1500, node_color='yellow', font_size=8, font_weight='bold')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("Graph.png", format="PNG")
plt.show()
```

It worked fine on Jupyter Notebook and using cmd `python graph.py`
But it never run on complied .exe file.

- Pyinstaller's executable file crashes
- Py2exe's executable flashed error message when open the first time and it closed immediately so I don't know what was the error

My networkx version: 2.5, matplotlib: 3.2.2, python 3.8.3, newest pyinstaller and py2exe

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried removing the `plt.show()`? If you only want to save the image, you don't need to show it, because figure window etc. may cause some problems.

Comment: @Sparky05 yes I had it removed, didn't run